# Can anyone please rectify this error in the below SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

```
create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

[image]

I'm running it on MySQL 5.5

Comment: Use `;` to terminate statements.

Comment: Seems ok to me... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ";"

```
create database android_api; /** Creating Database **/
use android_api; /** Selecting Database **/
create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the auto_increament from your query then run it.
for referrence go to this link and run your query....

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete

Comment: What relevance has your answer and the link you posted in regard to the question?